# UWP UserActivity in Timeline not navigating to correct page on click

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developing a UWP app that I'm trying to integrate with Windows Timeline. However, when I click the adaptive card for my app in Timeline, it always navigates to the homepage, instead of SecondPage. I suspect there is an error in OnActivated in App.xaml.cs with respect to Shell, or in my URI protocol, but I'm not sure. Any advice would be appreciated.

App.xaml.cs

```
    protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(Window.Current.Content is Shell shell))
        {
            shell = new Shell();

            Window.Current.Content = shell;

            if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
            {
                var uriArgs = e as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
                if (uriArgs != null)
                {
                    if (uriArgs.Uri.Host == "secondpage")
                    {
                        shell.RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), uriArgs);
                    }
                }
            }
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
```

SecondPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // If we were activated from a URI, say so.
        // A real app would use the information in the URI to restore state.

            await CreateUserActivityAsync();
    }

    async Task CreateUserActivityAsync()
    {
        // Get channel and create activity.
        UserActivityChannel channel = UserActivityChannel.GetDefault();
        UserActivity activity = await channel.GetOrCreateUserActivityAsync("MyActivityName");

        // Set deep-link and properties.
        activity.ActivationUri = new Uri("myapp:page?secondpage");
        activity.VisualElements.DisplayText = "Second Page";

        // Save to activity feed.
        await activity.SaveAsync();

        // Create a session, which indicates that the user is engaged
        // in the activity.
        _currentSession = activity.CreateSession();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Dispose the session, which indicates that the user is no longer
        // engaged in the activity.
        _currentSession?.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: have u tried using debugging with breakpoints in OnActivated method?

Comment: Yeah, the following line from App.xaml.cs does not run:                         `shell.RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), uriArgs);` i.e. the if statement isn't executed. It seems like it doesn't recognise `secondpage` as `Uri.Host`.

Comment: ahan wht is the value of uriArgs.Uri.Host ?

Comment: uriArgs.Uri.Host is an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your [UserActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.useractivities.useractivity) in your `CreateUserActivityAsync` method, you have configured a wrong format Uri, so the `uriArgs.Uri.Host` in your `OnActivated` method will be `""` and no any string value matches your string "secondpage". Please modify your Uri to be:

```
 // Set deep-link and properties.
 activity.ActivationUri = new Uri("myapp://secondpage?xxxxxx");
```

Then you can match your `uriArgs.Uri.Host == "secondpage"` in your `OnActivated` method.